# Trying to display a GUI in Session 0

Tags: c#, windows

I have searched everywhere and tried just about everything and I am starting to think this is not possible.
I have a service running in Session 0 (win7) as SYSTEM.I need to launch an external application. If I simply launch the external application as SYSTEM, the application launches and I can see the GUI (if I click over to Session 0 using UI0Detect). In addition to me being able to see it, my service that launched the application can actually take a screen shot of the GUI and send it back to my servers. - at this point all is good.

The issue - there are cases where the external application is not allowed to run under the SYSTEM context. In these cases I must launch as a different user. I have another service running as an actual user in Session 0. I then launch the external application as this other user. The external application is launched in Session 0, and I specify WinSta0\Default to ensure that the application GUI launches on the same desktop that my SYSTEM service can see. When this happens UI0Detect pops up giving me the impression that i will click over and see my window. When I get over to session 0 or when my service attempts a screen shot, there is just a small black box. It's almost like only the SYSTEM account can render windows in session 0 - is this true? anyone know if user accounts running in session 0 are able to render a GUI?

I am not looking for code on how to launch an application from session 0 to an active user desktop. That is well documented. What I need to know is how to pull off the reverse (sort of). I need to launch a GUI in session 0 from an account other than SYSTEM.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Services can run when there are no visual desktops--in which case nothing visual will be side and no user can interact with the UI.  What would you application do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "If the service type specifies SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS, the service must run in the LocalSystem account."

So there is no supported way to do what you're trying to do.  However, it might be possible to get it to work by getting the service that runs as SYSTEM to change the permissions on the desktop (and perhaps the window station) in question.  Keep in mind that sharing a desktop in this way means that if the application or the user account in question is compromised, it may be able to compromise the system account.

Alternatively, you could try creating a new desktop in session 0 (with appropriate permissions) and launching the application there.  I'm not sure if the interactive user would be able to see this desktop, but you could take a screenshot by launching another application in the same desktop (and preferably in the same user context) to take the screenshot on your behalf.

Comment: I was pretty sure I was going to get this answer. At least now I can stop wondering. Pretty cool learning experience with Windows programming for me.